# How to use custom DateTime.now in integration test for ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-core-webapi, integration

I have an integration test in my project that should use `DateTime.Now`.

This is my method:

```
public static ErrorResult CheckAvailabiliteOfOrderDeliveryInCurrentTime(string openingTime,string closingTime)
{
    var currentTimeString = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); 

    if (DateTime.Parse(openingTime + ":00") > DateTime.Parse(closingTime + ":00"))
    {
        if ((DateTime.Parse(currentTimeString) <= DateTime.Parse("23:59:00") && 
             DateTime.Parse(currentTimeString) > DateTime.Parse(openingTime + ":00")) || 
            (DateTime.Parse(currentTimeString) < DateTime.Parse(closingTime + ":00") && 
             DateTime.Parse(currentTimeString) >= DateTime.Parse("00:00:00")))
        {
            return ErrorResult.None;
        }
        else
        {
            return ErrorResult.OutOfDeliveryTime;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(currentTimeString) < DateTime.Parse(closingTime + ":00") && 
            DateTime.Parse(currentTimeString) > DateTime.Parse(openingTime + ":00"))
        {
            return ErrorResult.None;
        }
        else
        {
            return ErrorResult.OutOfDeliveryTime;
        }
    }
}
```

My handler method that call this method :

```
public async Task<OrderDto> Handle(CreateOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var validator = new CreateOrderCommandValidator();
    var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (!result.IsValid) 
         throw new ValidationException(result);

    var foodBusiness = await _context.FoodBusinesses.FindAsync(Guid.Parse(request.FoodBusinessId));

    if (foodBusiness == null)
        throw new NotFoundException(nameof(FoodBusiness), request.FoodBusinessId);

    if (request.Type == OrderTypes.Delivery)
    {   
        var isOutdeliveryTime = DateTimeHelpers.CheckAvailabiliteOfOrderDeliveryInCurrentTime(foodBusiness.OpeningTime, foodBusiness.ClosingTime);

        if (isOutdeliveryTime == ErrorResult.OutOfDeliveryTime)
        {
            var newOrder = new OrderDto();
            newOrder.errorDeliveryTimeAvailabilite = ErrorResult.OutOfDeliveryTime;

            return _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(newOrder);
        }
        else
        {
            var newOrder = await ExecuteOrderOperations(request, cancellationToken, foodBusiness);
            return _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(newOrder);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var newOrder = await ExecuteOrderOperations(request, cancellationToken, foodBusiness);
        return _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(newOrder);
    }
}
```

By default application us using `System.DateTime.Now`, but in the integration test, I need to use my own `DateTime.Now` - is there any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Don't use DateTime.Now directly. Instead create an interface `ISystemClock` with a property Now and for production an implementation just returns DateTime.Now, while in your tests you can return whatever needed. The same is true for all static methods you use from the framework and you like to mock in tests (e.g. Directory or File class). The approach is always the same. Create an interface with the desired methods, which in production just forward to the default static methods.

Comment: https://github.com/Testably/Testably.Abstractions

Comment: https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions

Answer (score 1):

Your opinions are:

1. Refactor the code to be testable. E.g. create a `ISystemClock` and have your unit test use a mock.
2. Purchase Visual Studio Enterprise and [use Microsoft Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) or some other third-party solution.